# Get All img tags out of xml file (jquery)

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following xml file

```
<gallery>
<album title="test" description="test" lgPath="/images/commphotos/">
    <img src="1130975173.jpg" />
    <img src="1475634985E.jpg" />
    <img src="1889677107.jpg" />
    <img src="1356256436.jpg" />
    <img src="834682273.jpg" />

</album>
</gallery>
```

I've been trying to read it using jquery to get out each of the img tags.
Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat the XML document like any other:

```
$(xml).find('img');
```

**Update:** This will give you a jQuery object containing all the tags as DOM elements. If you want, say, an array of the tags as strings, it gets more complicated:

```
var tarr = [];
$(xml).find('img').each(function() {
    tarr.push( $(this).clone().appendTo('<div/>').parent().html() );
});
```

To get just the `src` attributes:

```
var tarr = [];
$(xml).find('img').each(function() {
    tarr.push( $(this).attr('src') );
});
```

Comment: but yet didn't cross the line ;)

Comment: He said he wanted to "get out each of the img tags". Didn't say anything about attributes.

Comment: well i do that but it just returns an object how do you read each one?

Comment: @user719316 First, you tell us what you mean by "read". Do you want the `src` attributes, or the entire tags, or something else? Do you want this for every `img` tag at once, or one at a time?

Comment: it would be best if i had the entire <img>.

Comment: $(xml).find('img').each(function() {
alert($(this).text()); 


}    );
i tried above and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

With the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function, you can easily get all the `src` attributes of those `img`s into a Javascript array. Of course you can use `.each()` also, but it is much more elegant this way.

```
var srcArray = $(xml).find('img').map(function () {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RrLbm/)

In my example, `.get()` is used to create a simple array from the jQuery object returned.

Comment: I keep forgetting about the `.map()` method, probably because I always find it harder to read than just constructing the array myself. Good call.

Comment: @mblase75 Personally I find it much more readable than `.each()` for this purpose, but won't argue on tastes :).

Answer (score -1):

$(xml).find('img').attr('src')

Comment: This will return the `src` for the first `img` only, not for all of them.

Comment: Returning all of them would be meaningless. Should I construct an array to store the srcs? Oh wait, that's what the xml is already doing. This answer shows the OP how to access the heart of the information. Once you know how to grab a src, iterating over the rest of the items and DOING something is trivial.