# Get img tags from xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Since I have mootools used on a web page, jquery conflicts with it so I'm attempting to traverse the following xml file.

```
<gallery>
 <album title="test" description="test" lgPath="/images/commphotos/">
<img src="1130975173.jpg" />
<img src="1475634985E.jpg" />
<img src="1889677107.jpg" />
<img src="1356256436.jpg" />
<img src="834682273.jpg" />

</album>
</gallery>
```

One I return the javascript file using a standard ajax call.  How would I traverse it to get the image tags out.  Using responseText when returning the xml?  Can't use jquery.  I have no idea how to do mootools.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the conflict, you can use `jQuery` instead of `$`. If `$` is occupied by jQuery, use `$.noConflict()` prior continuing.

Then, use the [answer at your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983420/get-all-img-tags-out-of-xml-file-jquery), by replacing `$` by `jQuery`, or use:

```
var images = [];
jQuery(xml).find('img').each(function(){
    images.push(this.src);
})
```

Comment: $.noConflict() is not a function

Comment: and i apologize i'm using responseXML on return..i have the xml file, just wondering how to traverse it

Comment: Then `$` is not occupied by jQuery, but Mootools, as desired. Use `jQuery(..)` instead of `$(...)`, as mentioned at my answer.